# Handling sentry service error in flask logging

Tags: flask, logging, sentry

I have a flask project and it's logging process is handled by Sentry (before sentry I used stored logs in log files).

Last week a problem in my server caused Sentry to malfunction and I kept getting `refused connection` error while logging in my project.

I wandered is there any way to implement Sentry in flask logging so that in case of Sentry malfunction the logging is carried away in log files automatically?

This is how I use Sentry in my Flask project in **init** file:

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            template_folder='templates',
            static_folder='path',
            static_path='path')

...

if settings.SENTRY_DSN:
    from raven.contrib.flask import Sentry
    from raven.handlers.logging import SentryHandler
    sentry = Sentry(app, dsn=settings.SENTRY_DSN)
    sentry_handler = SentryHandler(settings.SENTRY_DSN)
    sentry_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(sentry_handler)
    limiter.logger.addHandler(sentry_handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use official sdk
Install Sentry for flask

```
pip install --upgrade 'sentry-sdk[flask]==0.14.4'
```

set your config

```
if settings.SENTRY_DSN:
    import sentry_sdk
    from sentry_sdk.integrations.flask import FlaskIntegration
    sentry_sdk.init(
        dsn=settings.SENTRY_DSN,
        integrations=[FlaskIntegration()]
    )
```

Comment: not sure if this is properly handled with the official SDK because, we are using it and still have some side effects in a Flask App when our Sentry server is down...